# Non-numeric argument to binary operator in MILPModel of ompr package

Tags: r

I am familiar with how to use `ompr::MIPModel` but I am trying to learn how to use `MILPModel` to take advantage of the model build speed. A simplified version of my model is below. I have two decision variables, `x` and `y`, binary and of equal length.  I have constraints on the sum of all the `x` decision variables, and the sum of all the `y` decision variables.  So far so good with `MILPModel`, I can build the model and solve it fast.

The problem is when I try to use the next constraint.  The LHS of this constraint multiplies the `x` binary decision variables by a numeric column in a dataframe of the same length, then multiplies that by a matrix where the rows are equal to the length of `x`.  Similar story in the RHS with the `y` variable.  I then iterate this constraint 20 times to represent all the columns of the matrix.

I've used constraints similar to this many times using `MIPModel`, but now when I try this I get an error message, `non-numeric argument to binary operator`.  I assume this has something to do with the `colwise` function, but I am completely lost on how to approach this, even after reading up on the ompr github site.

```
add_variable(x[i], i=1:10, type='binary') %>%
add_variable(y[i], i=1:10, type='binary') %>%
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i],i=1:10) <= 5) %>%
add_constraint(sum_expr(y[i],i=1:10) <= 3) %>%

#model builds and solves until this point...
add_constraint( 
sum_expr( x[i]* df$numeric_column[i] * matrix_a[i,j],i=1:10) <= 
sum_expr(  2* y[i]* df$numeric_column[i] * df$other_numeric_column[i] * matrix_a[i,j],i=1:10), 
j=1:20)
```

Comment: I can confirm the error message but don't know the fix, so I contacted Dirk Schumacher, the author of OMPR. He said he'll take a look next week.

Comment: Answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294305/ompr-milpmodel-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator/63321627#63321627

Comment: @prubin I answered in my crosspost in SO.  There were some gymnastics involved in adapting the matrix multiplication in the last constraint, to allow for vectorization.  Also - I learned about OMPR from your blog a few years ago, thank you so much for what you've done for the OR community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a follow-up on how to style matrix multiplication-type constraints and objective function values.  This has been a major pain point for me, and now that I have a template, this will be a real productivity boost as I switch to being "MILPModel native".

Replace SYMPHONY with the solver of your choice...

````
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
library(ROI.plugin.symphony)


rm(list=ls())



set.seed(42)

#in this example, mat1 is a numeric matrix representing coefficients for 40 binary decision variables
mat1 <- matrix(ncol=10,nrow=4,runif(400))

#define this function, it will be necessary for matrix multiplication inside a MILPModel
matrix_multiplication_fcn <- function(static_matrix, row_variable, column_variable){
  vapply(seq_along(row_variable), function(k) static_matrix[row_variable[k], column_variable[k]], numeric(1L))  }

milp_model <- ompr::MILPModel() %>%
  add_variable(assign_units[rowindex,colindex], rowindex=1:4,colindex=1:10,type='binary') %>%
  #total binaries ==10
  add_constraint(sum_expr( assign_units[rowindex,colindex],rowindex=1:4,colindex=1:10 )==10 ) %>%
  
  #sum of binaries * mat1 <= 7
  add_constraint( sum_expr( ompr::colwise(
    matrix_multiplication_fcn(static_matrix=mat1,row_variable=rowindex,column_variable=colindex)) *
                              assign_units[rowindex,colindex], 
                            rowindex = 1:4, colindex = 1:10) <= 7) %>%

  #objective: maximize value
  set_objective(sum_expr(
    ompr::colwise(matrix_multiplication_fcn(static_matrix=mat1,row_variable=rowindex,column_variable=colindex)) * 
      assign_units[rowindex,colindex],
    rowindex=1:4,colindex=  1:10),sense='max')
    
milp_model_out <-  milp_model %>%   
  ompr::solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "symphony",verbosity=-2,gap_limit=0,time_limit=180, node_limit=-1,first_feasible=FALSE))


#same with MIPModel

mip_model <- ompr::MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(assign_units[rowindex,colindex], rowindex=1:4,colindex=1:10,type='binary') %>%
  #total binaries ==10
  add_constraint(sum_expr( assign_units[rowindex,colindex],rowindex=1:4,colindex=1:10 )==10 ) %>%
  
  #sum of binaries * mat1 <= 7
  add_constraint( sum_expr( mat1[rowindex,colindex] * assign_units[rowindex,colindex], 
                            rowindex = 1:4, colindex = 1:10) <= 7) %>%
  
  #objective: maximize value
  set_objective(sum_expr(mat1[rowindex,colindex] * assign_units[rowindex,colindex],
    rowindex=1:4,colindex=  1:10),sense='max')

mip_model_out <-  mip_model %>%   
  ompr::solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "symphony",verbosity=-2,gap_limit=0,time_limit=180, node_limit=-1,first_feasible=FALSE))

#compare results, both should be slightly above 7 (thus slightly violating the constraint), I assume due to floating point issues
mip_model_out
milp_model_out
```
````